# How do format date notation from SQL database to a HTML page using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Working on a small project that renders a database from SQL to a HTML page using Python Flask.

Trying to change the date notation from "%y-%m-%d %H:%M" to "%d-%m-%y %H:%M".

Using the below code:

```
   </tr>
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[4].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")}}</td>
        <td>{{item[5].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")}}</td>
        <td>{{item[7].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")}}</td>
        <td>{{item[10].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")}}</td>
        <td>{{item[12].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")}}</td>
        <td>{{item[13]}}</td>
    </tr>
```

when I run the code in the localhost i get the following error.

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'strftime'

Tried to define an own filter, didn't work either.

Hope all clear, Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `items`?

Comment: Like this? results_ABC = session.query(table1).filter(table1.c.Location == 'LocationABC').order_by(
        table1.c.Completed_sampling.desc())
    return render_template("ABC.html", items=results_ABC.all())

Comment: More like `[['val1', 'val2', 'val3', ....], ...]`. The result of `print(items)`.

Comment: [('12345', 'productname', '878', 'Location ABC', 'typemovement', datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 22, 40), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 22, 40), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 22, 40), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 23, 15), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 23, 20), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 23, 25), 'employee 1', '2021-06-16 00:25:04.1700000', 0)

Comment: - PS already remove this 'typemovement (item[4])  <td>{{item[4].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")}}</td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use datetime object not string. `datetime(2013, 10, 31, 18, 23, 29, 227)`,

You can create a custom filter in python like

```
from datetime import datetime

def date(d):
     d =  datetime.strptime(d,"%y-%m-%d %H:%M")
     d.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
     return d

app.add_template_filter(date)
```

In jinja use like this `{{item[2] | date}}`

Comment: thanks. Used your code. got the following error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str). Also the IDE (Pycharm) indicates that d.strftime() = Unresolved attribute reference 'strftime' for class '(datetime)'

Comment: I edited the answer and used strptime to convert to datetime object.

Comment: Tried your latest code. Followed by error TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime. tried to use (str(d). didn't work either. I am afraid something wrong in my code while creating the table?

Comment: datetime.strptime(str(d), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") work but no changes when rendering the database into Html.

Comment: Can you please tell me what items is because first it gave error that it was string now it says it is date time.datetime . Try printing type(d) at top of function.

Comment: [('12345', 'productname', '878', 'Location ABC', 'typemovement', datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 22, 40), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 22, 40), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 22, 40), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 23, 15), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 23, 20), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 16, 23, 25), 'employee 1', '2021-06-16 00:25:04.1700000', 0)

Comment: - PS already remove this 'typemovement (item[4])  <td>{{item[4].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")}}</td>

Comment: the date is already in datetime.datetime object it should work with the one above code you used above might be you have used strftime with one of the strings, recheck your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233881/discussion-between-kenny-van-der-pluijm-and-charchit).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have string values mixed with `datetime.datetime` objects in `items`. Before passing `data` to `jinja`, I suggest you pre-format you values:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
new_items = [[i[0], i[1], i[2], i[5].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M"), 
             i[6].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M"), i[7].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M"), 
             i[10].strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M"), 
             datetime(*map(int, re.findall('\d+', i[12])[:-1])).strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M"),
             i[13]] for i in items]

#[['12345', 'productname', '878', '16-06-21 22:40', '16-06-21 22:40', '16-06-21 22:40', '16-06-21 23:25', '16-06-21 00:25', 0]]
```

Now, in your template:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        {%for i in item%}
           <td>{{i}}</td>
        {%endfor%}
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```